# Missing Dependency issue when trying to install apc extension for php

Tags: alternative-php-cache

I'm trying to install apc extension for php according to this tutorial: http://2bits.com/articles/installing-php-apc-gnulinux-centos-5.html but can't successfully run the first command. Here is what I get:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Repository base is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository updates is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository extras is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository centosplus is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository contrib is listed more than once in the configuration
Determining fastest mirrors
Plesk                                                    |  951 B     00:00
Plesk-Third-Party                                        |  951 B     00:00
base                                                     | 1.1 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pear.noarch 1:1.4.9-6.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-devel for package: php-pear
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php-devel
--> Processing Dependency: autoconf for package: php-devel
--> Processing Dependency: automake for package: php-devel
--> Running transaction check
---> Package autoconf.noarch 0:2.59-12 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: imake for package: autoconf
---> Package automake.noarch 0:1.9.6-2.3.el5 set to be updated
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php-devel
--> Running transaction check
---> Package imake.x86_64 0:1.0.2-3 set to be updated
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php-devel
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 (base)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

Does anyone what these two errors mean and how should I fix it?

```
php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64 (base)
```

I think this is the reason why I can't install apc on my server. The server is running centos 5.6, with php 5.3.8. Control panel is plesk 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did  you install php-5.3.8?  The php-devel package has to version match with your installed php.  Install the corresponding php-devel first and then try again with installing php-pear.  I don't know if that package will be looking for a particular version of php, though.  If so, you'll need to find the version-appropriate php-pear package.